# How does ng.core.ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush work?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

If change detection strategy is set to onPush then if component attributes change then only component should be re-rendered.

Here is an example code:

```
        var SampleComponent1 = ng.core.Component({
            selector: "sampleone",
            template: "{{value}}",
            viewProviders: [ng.core.ChangeDetectorRef],
            changeDetection: ng.core.ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush
        }).Class({
            constructor: [ng.core.ChangeDetectorRef, function(cd){
                this.cd = cd;
            }],
            ngOnInit: function(){
                this.value = 1;
                setInterval(function(){
                    this.value++;
                }.bind(this), 2000)
            }
        })

        var App = ng.core.Component({
            selector: "app",
            directives: [SampleComponent1],
            template: "<sampleone ></sampleone>"
        }).Class({
            constructor: function(){

            }
        })
```

Here even if attribute doesn't change the template is rendered? Is this a bug or I misunderstood onPush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a bug. You made a mistake:

```
changeDetection: ng.core.ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush
```

**OnPush** instead onPush

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IdGZxhRfdOvHwJyThqW7?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

See @yurzui's answer for the fix, but I wanted to comment on

> If change detection strategy is set to onPush then if component attributes change then only component should be re-rendered.

It's a bit more than that. According to [Savkin's blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2) (well, it is buried in a comment to @vivainio),
with `OnPush`, Angular will only check the component for changes (i.e., check the template bindings) when

- any of its **input properties** (not "component attributes") changes
- it fires an event (e.g., a button click)
- an observable fires an event, and the `async` pipe is used in the view with that observable

For more info about how `OnPush` works, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845604/215945

Answer (score 0):

#### Angular 4+ Answer

The structure of Angular components has changed since this question was asked.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dummy-component',
    templateUrl: './dummy-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: [],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DummyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() sampleInput: string;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.sampleInput) {
      // Run any trigger when the sampleInput has changed
    }

  }
}
```